# Hypothesis Test for Random Variables with Different Variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, robust

I have a dataset consisting of type 0 and type 1 articles and their corresponding page views.  I want to see whether type 0's true mean is greater than type 1's true mean (up to statistical significance).  However, they don't have the same variance which I know is a pre-req for most hypothesis tests.

What else might I look into to be able to say, with confidence, that the true mean of type 0 is greater than the true mean of type 1.  For what it's worth, my data is almost certainly not distributed normally.

Answer (score 4):

You can perform a robust *t*-test. One option is Yuen's test for [trimmed means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean). It trims the outermost values (helping with non-normality), then performs the *t*-test adjusting the degrees of freedom using a [Welch-type adjustment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) to account for unequal variances.

This test is implemented in the `yuen` function in the [`WRS2` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WRS2/index.html) in R. This is one of many robust alternatives.

You could also model the problem as a robust regression. These are examples of how to do this and interpret the results in [SAS](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/dae/robust-regression/), [R](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/robust-regression/), and [Stata](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/dae/robust-regression/).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the Mann-Whitney test. Here is the wiki page on this test. The test in R is implemented in the wilcox.test function in base R.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test

The R code to do perform both of these tests is:

```
n<-100
y<- rgamma(n, shape=1, scale=1)
x<- rgamma(n, shape=2, scale=4)
wilcox.test(y,x, alternative ="less")
```

use the alternative to specify less than or greater than depending on your setup.

Comment: OP is interested in means. The Mann-Whitney test does not test the equality of means.

Comment: Yes you're right Mann-Whitney tests equality of medians. Upvoting your answer on Windsorized means.

Comment: I didn't know it tested equality of medians. I thought it tested whether one score randomly drawn from one sample would be equal to another randomly drawn from the other sample, the alternative hypothesis to this is referred to as stochastic dominance. After reading up on the test, if one wants to comment on the equality of medians, you need to establish homogeneity of variance. If you just want to establish stochastic dominance, then you don't need to consider homogeneity of variance.